# Tizen Native: Callback set for hardware buttons are not called

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app, efl

I set the callback for hardware buttons Back and More using the code:

```
static void win_more_cb(void* data, Evas_Object* obj, void* event_info) {
    appdata_s* ad = data;
    if (ad->ctxpopup != NULL) evas_object_del(ad->ctxpopup);

    ad->ctxpopup = elm_ctxpopup_add(ad->win);
    elm_object_style_set(ad->ctxpopup, "more/default");

    eext_object_event_callback_add(ad->ctxpopup, EEXT_CALLBACK_BACK, _eext_ctxpopup_back_cb, NULL);
    eext_object_event_callback_add(ad->ctxpopup, EEXT_CALLBACK_MORE, _eext_ctxpopup_back_cb, NULL);
    evas_object_smart_callback_add(ad->ctxpopup, "dismissed", ctxpopup_dismissed_cb, NULL);

    elm_ctxpopup_item_append(ad->ctxpopup, "Add", NULL, ctxpopup_add_cb, NULL);

    move_more_ctxpopup(ad->ctxpopup);
    evas_object_show(ad->ctxpopup);
}
```

But, it's never called.

*Notice: I used a specially created `_eext_ctxpopup_back_cb`, that writes debug log to check if it's called, instead of standard `eext_ctxpopup_back_cb`. I tried with `eext_ctxpopup_back_cb` too.*

With this code, when I tap a hardware button (Back or More), it calls the callback, which was set for the main window. The `_eext_ctxpopup_back_cb` is never called!

Here is the code, which sets callbacks for the main window:

```
eext_object_event_callback_add(ad->win, EEXT_CALLBACK_BACK, win_back_cb, ad);
eext_object_event_callback_add(ad->win, EEXT_CALLBACK_MORE, win_more_cb, ad);
```

So, it looks like `eext_object_event_callback_add()` does not actually set the callback for Ctxpopup or Ctxpopup does not receive `EEXT_CALLBACK_BACK` and `EEXT_CALLBACK_MORE` events for some reason.

I saw usage of `eext_object_event_callback_add()` with Ctxpopup in Tizen Native API documentation and in many sample applications, so I assume it should have worked, but it does not.

Please advice.

**Update:**

I deployed my not-yet-ready app to a Tizen device and the Back button worked there! So, this is something in the Debug environment or emulator (it does not work in emulator).

Comment: Did you go through this link (https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/native-application/user-interface/efl/hardware-input-handling/managing-menu-and-back-key-events) ?

Comment: Yes, I did. That's one of many documents, I used to implement support for More/Back buttons.

Comment: On which platform you're working? Tizen mobile or wearable? Please share here. Also please share Tizen version of development device.

Comment: Mobile 2.4. I'm using emulator. Mobile 2.4 there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in "update", this happened only in emulator. On a real device (Samsung Z1) the hardware Back button worked fine with the specified code.

But, I managed to fix this for emulator too:

I figured out that the `EEXT_CALLBACK_BACK` is not called for a `ctxpopup` (as well as for `naviframe`, that I added later), if any of the hardware callbacks (`EEXT_CALLBACK_BACK` or `EEXT_CALLBACK_MORE`) is registered for the main window (`ad->win`). As soon as I moved `EEXT_CALLBACK_MORE` to a `naviframe`, the hardware Back button started to work in emulator as well.

So, generally, it looks like these two callbacks should not ever be set for the main window. If they are, child components do not receive hardware Back and More events.